# Angular Library inherits Parent application modules

Tags: angular

Can an angular application inherits a service 
inside the core application and use its functions ?

i have a core application containing multiple libraries, i need all the libraries to have access to a specific service inside the core application is it possible ?

Comment: you can move the service to a shared module and import it anywhere

Comment: oh okay. can you please tell me how i can do this ? i am new to shared modules and i was not able to find any documentation online about this. i thought about a way to define a service interface in my library that will be pointing to any parent's core application and search for a similar service and use it

Comment: Here is the official documentation from angular: https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules

Answer (score 0):

You will have a module called `SharedModule`. In it, you will add all the services / components that you need to use it on multiple modules. In this way, you can just import it and use the service / components you need.
Good to mention too that you can make the service accessible anywhere in the app by provide it in the AppModule, or add `providedIn: 'root'`

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
```

You can find more info [here](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services)

Comment: Hello, here in my case i have two separate projects in angular. in some cases the second project will need to be used in the first one. so is there any way to access the service without creating the same service in my second project ?

Comment: is my real use case i have a core application and i am constantly adding new libraries after build, these libraries are being rendered dynamically by the core application. i need those libraries to be able to inherit a service from the parent core application

Comment: Yes for sure. Just do the SharedModule, and You can just import it from there. something like `import { SharedModule } from '../../THE/Relative/PATH'`

Comment: What about moving it into an Angular library? https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries